# Odoo - 8 How to get the updated field value and the time of updation from a form?

Tags: field, odoo, odoo-8

[Odoo 8] How to get the updated field value and the time of updation from a form? 
write them in separate fields respectively "changed value" ,"Changed Time" in Odoo8

Comment: Please kindly elaborate your question.

Comment: for example if I change the customer name in the form that old customer name should be stored in some other field and the edited time also should be stored in another field.

do you get my question Vignesh?

Comment: For this you don't need to add an extra field, always keep a trace on your message log, whenever a write action is triggered get the updated value and write in the message log along with user_id, so that you can always keep a track of record who edited the form and changes they have made.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 good options for you:

1. You can use track_visibility on field definitions. There are many examples in the odoo code, e. g. sale.order field state.
2. You can use the modules audittrail (V7 or minor) or [auditlog](https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/8.0) (V8+)